# How to update attribute of object from model via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been struggling to follow other answers and documentation for a really simple question.

I understand the 'skinny' controller and 'fat model' concept. However, I am really struggling with passing data between the controller and model.

For example, I simply want to update an attribute when an action is called.

```
 class BlogsController < ApplicationController


 before_action :find_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :active]

   def active
      @blog.active = true
      @blog.save
      Blog.send_subscription_emails
      render template: "/blogs/backend/active"
   end
 end
```

This obviously looks bad as the model should have access to the database to change the attribute. How is this done as I can't pass this instance variable across into the model. It isn't the same 'instance' as it was in the controller.

For example,

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  def self.turn_active
      @blog.active = true
  end
end
```

This won't work. What are my options?

Comment: you can have a method `activate` on the `Blog` model: `def activate ; self.active = true ; end` and then in your controller you would use `def active ; @blog.activate ; [...] ; end` (`;` is a shorthand for a newline)

Comment: I'm surprised that would work. The instance variable in the controller has access to methods from the model?!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question... But as long as you have set `@blog` to be a Blog instanciated object, if you define a _public instance method_ on `Blog` object you can call it from anywhere.

Comment: It works! I need to get my head over this. Thanks.

Comment: I'd be happy to mark a correct answer if you can be bothered to write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
# in blog model
def activate
  update_attributes(active: true)
end

# in controller
def active
  @blog.activate
  Blog.send_subscription_emails
  render template: "/blogs/backend/active"
end
```